# Remove backslashes "\" from title from csv file in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv

I am working on a script that export data from mysql in csv file. Its work perfectly.

When I enter title of the song with apostrophes from admin panel like `test'123'` the data save in database like this `test\'123\'`.

[image]

Now when I export the data into csv file, the title save as it is with backslashes '\' like this:

[image]

Now I want that when I export the data from database into csv file the back slashes will remove only from csv file, not from the database.

Here is my code to exprot data:

```
$query = "SELECT plist.playlist_id, plist.playlist_name, plist.playlist_shortcode, psong.song_id, psong.list_order,
              psong.song_playlist, psong.mp3, psong.ogg, psong.title, psong.buy, psong.buyy, psong.buyyy, psong.price, psong.cover, 
              psong.artist
              FROM " . $pre . "hmp_songs As psong
              LEFT JOIN " . $pre . "hmp_playlists As plist
              On plist.playlist_name = psong.song_playlist
              Where plist.playlist_id IS NOT NULL
              And plist.playlist_name IS NOT NULL
              And plist.playlist_shortcode IS NOT NULL
              And psong.song_id IS NOT NULL
              And psong.list_order IS NOT NULL
              And psong.song_playlist IS NOT NULL
              And psong.mp3 IS NOT NULL
              And psong.ogg IS NOT NULL
              And psong.title IS NOT NULL
              And psong.buy IS NOT NULL
              And psong.buyy IS NOT NULL
              And psong.buyyy IS NOT NULL
              And psong.price IS NOT NULL
              And psong.cover IS NOT NULL
              And psong.artist IS NOT NULL";

    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die("Error executing query: ".mysqli_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $line = "";
    $comma = "";

    foreach($row as $name => $value) {
        $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $name) . '"';
        $comma = ",";
    }

    $line .= "\n";
    $out = $line;

    mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $line = "";
        $comma = "";
        foreach($row as $value) {
            $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"';
            $comma = ",";
        }
        $line .= "\n";
        $out .= $line;
    }

    $csv_file_name = 'HMP_'.date('Ymd_His').'.csv'; # CSV FILE NAME WILL BE table_name_yyyymmdd_hhmmss.csv
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$csv_file_name);
    header("Content-Description:File Transfer");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    echo __($out,"hmp");
    exit;
```

How can I do this because I have no idea. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP function `stripslashes` will work for you.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";
echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

> Output
>
> Is your name O'reilly?

**Usage in your code:**

```
foreach($row as $value) {
    $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', stripslashes($value)) . '"';
    $comma = ",";
}
```

Comment: thanx alot .. your answer help me out ... i accept your answer after few minutes

Comment: Have updated my post with code where you can make use of `stripslashes`